# Can't I turn off Deno.signal after I set it up?

Tags: javascript, signals, deno

```
let sig = Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT)

await sig

console.log('hi')
```

When the code above is executed and the SIGINT is passed to the process, the process is resumed by the first SIGINT.

However, the problem is that
after handling the signal,
SIGINT doesn't work anymore.

So, I tried to make it work.

```
let sig = Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT)

await sig

sig.dispose()

console.log('hi')
```

And this is what I've got:

`sig.dispose` immediately resolve `sig` whenever `await` occurs to `sig`.(whether SIGINT is delivered or not)
For `asyncIterator`, it meant to return `done: true`.

It had nothing to do with returning SIGINT to its original state.

Is this intended??

Answer (score 1):

The usually expected way of handling a stream of signals is as follows:

```js
const sig = Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT);

// NOTICE: you might want to have a task running in the meantime to test this.
// Signals belong to the type of optional/unref-ed promises, in that awaiting
// on such promises does not block the runtime from exiting.
// You might want to add the line below for testing purposes.
setTimeout(() => {}, 100000);

// Async iterator. You can probably wrap it in a function such it does not
// block top level execution
for await (const _ of sig) {
  console.log("SIGINT captured");
}
```

`SignalStream` returned by `Deno.signal` indeed has a `.then` method, such that you can also go with this style:

```js
const sig = Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT);

setTimeout(() => {}, 100000);

while (true) {
  await sig;
  console.log("SIGINT captured");
}
```

It should work to be awaited multiple times. An example below correctly exits the process after 3 SIGINT triggers (locally verified to be working):

```js
const sig = Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT);

const timeout = setTimeout(() => {}, 100000);

await sig;
console.log("SIGINT captured #1");
await sig;
console.log("SIGINT captured #2");
await sig;
console.log("SIGINT captured #3, exiting");
clearTimeout(timeout);

console.log("DONE");
```

`sig.dispose()`, as presented by the question, indeed does the job of unbinding the signal from `sig` and causes the awaiting promise to be woken immediately. This is to allow the async iterator to immediately exit from the loop if you have one. After calling `.dispose()`, the original `sig` is no longer usable (due to backing signal resource being closed and removed from internal resource table). You have to create a new `sig` from calling `Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT)` again.

```js
const sig1 = Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT);

const exitBlocker = setTimeout(() => {}, 100000);

await sig1;
console.log("SIGINT received by sig1. Disposing sig1");
sig1.dispose();

const sig2 = Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT);

await sig1; // This should resolve immediately, even without signal
console.log("sig1 resolves immediately, but no actual signal happened");

await sig2;
console.log("SIGINT received by sig2. This is the real deal.");
await sig2;
console.log("SIGINT received by sig2 again. Preparing for exit.");

clearTimeout(exitBlocker);
console.log("DONE");
```

You will see the following if you run above locally:

```
^CSIGINT received by sig1. Disposing sig1
sig1 resolves immediately, but no actual signal happened
^CSIGINT received by sig2. This is the real deal.
^CSIGINT received by sig2 again. Preparing for exit.
DONE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.
But what I'm really concerned about is that "After sig1 is disposed, SIGINT doesn't work as interrupting the process"

Comment: In the above example(where sig2 is not defined), in case of not clearing the exitBlocker, the process won't stop even if you send additional SIGINT.
(and you must wait for the blocker ends itself, or send SIGKILL instead)

Comment: @kwonryul I remember this was some quirks due to the underlying Rust crates (Tokio) we use atm. I briefly went through the underlying code of both Tokio and even its upstream signal-hook-registry, and noticed that once a signal is registered, even if all handlers have been dropped, the default is never restored (they never reapply `SIG_DFL`): https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/138eef352671aadffca304d62c69cb2582e64f2a/tokio/src/signal/unix.rs#L346-L361

This is an interesting thing the team can discuss, but for now we have to bear with it (`signal()` is unstable so there might be changes)

Comment: @kwonryul Submitting an issue for tracking purposes: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7164